# Find column value in another bigger column value located in another worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

In one worksheet, I have the following data:

```
    Contract    Status  Effective date  Expiry date
    20004         A          12/1/2010  11/30/2015
```

In a second worksheet, I have the following data:

```
    Customer    Sales org
    A25B020004  3000
    A25B020004  4000
    A00002064   3000
    A00002064   6000
    ....        ....
```

here's what I'm trying to do. I want to find all instances in the second worksheet where I can find the contract 20004 from the first worksheet. 
As you can see, the contract in the second worksheet is in a different format (it has A25B020004 instead of just the number 20004). First I need to be able to search 20004 in the second worksheet, find all instances where it happens, and then return how many sales org are attached to that specific Contract.

My results should look something like this:

```
Contract  Number of Sales Org     Sales Org
20004           2                 3000
20004           2                 4000
```

I'm completely new to Excel. I'm not asking for a step by step solution but could someone direct me to what kind of functions I should be looking at? My main problem right now is trying to find 20004 in the Second Worksheets contract format. Aka how do I search for 20004 in A25B020004? Then, How do I count the number of occurrences of that contract happening?

Comment: The number of sales can be solved by a simple wildcard `COUNTIF`. The `Sales Org` column, personally, I'll deal with using VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment above, the `Number of Sales Org` can be gotten by using a simple wildcard `COUNTIF`.

See below screenshot:

[image]

Basically, I added `*` at the beginning and end, which turns `20004` to `*20004*`. With this, you can have preceding and succeeding characters for `20004` and `COUNTIF` will still be able to find it. If you're sure that `20004` will only appear at the end, remove the second `*` as that is not good practice.

Adjust accordingly to your spreadsheet and let us know of the results.

**EDIT:**

Addressing the modified issue, use this code instead:

```
Sub GetAllData()

    Dim Sh1 As Worksheet, Sh2 As Worksheet
    Dim StrToFind As String, ContractNameLastRow As Long
    Dim RngToLookIn As Range, Cell As Range, RngOfStr As Range
    Dim CountOfSpecificName As Long

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set Sh1 = .Sheets("Sheet1") 'Modify accordingly.
        Set Sh2 = .Sheets("Sheet2") 'Modify accordingly.
    End With

    Set RngOfStr = Sh1.Range("A1")
    StrToFind = RngOfStr.Value 'Modify accordingly.
    ContractNameLastRow = Sh2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'Make sure it refers to column of contract names.
    Set RngToLookIn = Sh2.Range("A1:A" & ContractNameLastRow) 'Modify starting row accordingly.

    CountOfSpecificName = Application.CountIf(RngToLookIn, "*" & StrToFind & "*")
    RngOfStr.Resize(CountOfSpecificName, 1).Value = StrToFind
    RngOfStr.Offset(0, 1).Resize(CountOfSpecificName, 1).Value = CountOfSpecificName

    For Each Cell In RngToLookIn
        If InStr(1, Cell.Value, StrToFind) > 1 Then
            RngOfStr.Offset(0, 2).Value = Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value
            Set RngOfStr = RngOfStr.Offset(1, 0)
        End If
    Next Cell

End Sub
```

This assumes two things: the contract number you want to search for is in `A1` in `Sheet1`. The list you want to refer to starts in `A1` as well in `Sheet2`. Modify accordingly if not. This will change the data in `A1` in `Sheet` to contain all the data from `Sheet2` pertaining to the contract number. See my screenshots below.

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

**After running code:**

[image]

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: awesome, that solves one of my questions. now on to the next part. Thanks!

Comment: I would, except that I realized I mistook what I wanted from the excel help. Please look above for the edit on what I actually need done rather than what I thought I needed done.

Comment: amazing! one last query. Are there any beginners guide to VBA scripting that you can recommend or should I just use the tried and tested method of googling my way through problems? Thank you again!

Comment: @user2832803: Thanks for accepting. I taught myself mostly by Google and MSDN database. Anything I don't understand in someone else's code, I looked up in MSDN database. Eventually, I came across the ever-useful books by John Walkenbach. Check them out. Good luck!